# problems when read file in CLion (JetBrain)

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

I just install CLion and try to play around with it. But I meet some problems when reading a file and the console doesn't display as I expected, this is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void readFile(const char *fileName);

int main() {
    readFile("test.txt");
}

void readFile(const char *fileName) {
    ifstream file(fileName);
    string s1;
    file >> s1;
    cout << "s1 = " << s1;
}
```

and here is my file: test.txt

```
hello
```

this is the result:

```
C:\Users\hongn\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\85e35c99\85e35c99\Debug\Test.exe
s1 =
Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I try:

```
int a;
cout << "a = ";
cin >> a;
cout << "a is: " << a;
```

this is the result:

```
C:\Users\hongn\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\85e35c99\85e35c99\Debug\Test.exe
a =3
a = 3
a is: 3
Process finished with exit code 0
```

After I typed 3, the row "`a = 3`" appear.
It is not the expected result, so redundant, why the line "`a = 3`" appear 2 times? How can I fix this?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Probably `test.txt` is not where your application is looking for it.

Comment: It is on the same folder with the main.cpp

Comment: I think, may be my mingw is not suit with Clion. I have try to install more than one mingw, but all of them get the same result, I can't not read file test.txt, while It perfectly run with CodeBlock.

Comment: 1) Set the "working directory" in your Run/Debug configuration, otherwise you don't know what path `"test.txt"` is going to be looked for in. 2) I've had CLion garble the output of my programs before, usually running it a couple of times cleared it up. It also seems to strip blank lines, so run it from a terminal to be sure before blaming your code :)

Answer (score 1):

- you should add command to CMakeLists.txt

```
FILE(COPY data.csv DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
```

- change data.csv to your filename